# Why procfs mount option only working on remount?

Tags: linux, kernel, mount, proc

I have written own init process (pid 1) for my system, to improve security I decided to add `hidepid=2` while mounting `procfs` in `/proc` location (`procfs` not mounted by default).

After mounting the `procfs` I ran the `mount` command to check everything mount fine with given mount option, I noticed `hidepid=2` was not listed in option. After some time I found `hidepid=2` is able to add in list only after `remount`.

I also confirmed the behavior using command line too, like below

- initially `/proc` was not mounted with `procfs`
- executed `mount -t proc -o hidepid=2 proc /proc`
- executed `mount`, showed `proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)`
- executed `mount -t proc -o remount,hidepid=2 proc /proc`
- executed `mount`, showed `proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime,hidepid=2)`

Anyone kindly explain me why I was not able to mount `procfs` with `hidepid=2` in single attempt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a commit in the Linux kernel (https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=69879c01a0c3f70e0887cfb4d9ff439814361e46) that says:

> In addition removing the unnecessary complexity of the kernel mount
>   fixes a regression that caused the proc mount options to be ignored.
>   Now that the initial mount of proc comes from userspace, those mount
>   options are again honored.  This fixes Android's usage of the proc
>   hidepid option.

So it seems this is a bug in the Linux kernel and currently (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/69879c01a0c3f70e0887cfb4d9ff439814361e46), it is fixed only in the release candidate tags of the v5.7 version (v5.7-rc4, v5.7-rc3, v5.7-rc2 and v5.7-rc1).

Comment: Also, thanks to noodly from #gynvaelstream on freenode who pointed out this commit (but didn't have an account here to post an answer) :).

Comment: Does this commit mean one _can_ now use options to mount `procps` on `/proc`? If so, how? (I suppose `systemd` mounts `/proc` now on Systemd systems like mine, does it have a config option perhaps?)