# Mounting proc with hidepid option doesn’t hide procs as expected, why?

Tags: mount, proc

I have a regular proc fs mounted at /proc by default.

(I’m root for all of the following commands)

I’m mounting the same again at a different location with hidepid option set like so:

```
mount -t proc -o hidepid=2 proc /some/dir/proc
```

The mount works and I can see the same output from `ls /proc` And `ls /some/dir/proc`.

Then I run:

```
setpriv —-reuid 1002 ls /proc
```

And the output is still the same. No procs are hidden from uid 1002 - which is a non root user.

I checked if setpriv was working and if I do `setpriv -—reuid 1002 ls /root/` I get permission denied as expected.

It seems the hidepid option is having no effect. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to `hidepid`, there's the `gid` option:

> `gid=gid` (since Linux 3.3)
> Specifies the ID of a group whose members are authorized
> to learn process information otherwise prohibited by
> `hidepid`

It doesn't explicitly say that, but on my system it seems that it defaults to zero if not given. (I didn't check the source, though.) So, try with something like:

```
setpriv --regid 1002 --clear-groups --reuid 1002 ls /proc/
```

Also, there's a bug that causes the mount options for `proc` set at mount time to be ignored. Setting them with `-oremount` afterwards works. This is fixed in Linux 5.7, see: [Why procfs mount option only working on remount?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/584054/170373)

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried with regid and clear-groups. No dice. Still lists all the procs.

Comment: There is a bug in pre 5.7 linux kernel version that ignores the hidepid option while mounting proc, as pointed out in this answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/584897/224904

So I upgraded my linux kernel to 5.10 from 5.6 and it magically works! But it won't work without regid and clear-groups options as you pointed out. So yours is the right answer. 

If you can mention the bug in your answer, it will be complete and may help future users. Thanks.

Comment: @Roy, oh, wow. I would have never guessed. I just tried with a remount on `/proc` without thinking . Thanks for the pointer.